Expressions in Fermat Last Theorem style (modular)
I have found quite funny expression for "counterexample" of Fermat Last Theorem which is true but ... in the range of modular arithmetic.
We have $5^3+2^3\equiv3^3\pmod {53}.$
Let us notice that in mod $53$, from occurring here expressions only $5^3>53$.
Is it any procedure which can identify similar modular expressions or the only   way here is to use trial and error?
The given conditions are that the expression $x^n$ should be greater that modulus which is at the same time made from digits $x$ and $n$, other expressions $y^n$, $z^n$ should be less than modulus.

If $p\equiv2\pmod{3},$ there will be lots of solutions, modulo $p$ because $u\mapsto u^3$ will be $1-1.$ More generally, of $p\not\equiv 1\pmod q,$ with $p,q$ prime, then $u\mapsto u^q$ is one-to-one modulo $p,$ and so there will be solutions to $a^q+b^q\equiv c^q\pmod{p}.$

Modulo $53,$ we get, for any $a,b,$ that $$(a^{35})^3+(b^{35})^3\equiv((a+b)^{35})^3\pmod{53}.$$

@ThomasAndrews but at least one from $(a^{35})^3, (b^{35})^3$  should be less than $53$

You can always replace $a^{35}$ and $b^{35}$ by $a^{35}\bmod{53}$ and $b^{35}\bmod {53}.$ You will get still a lot of solutions. Indeed, what we see is that given any $u,v,$ $u^3+v^3$ is a cube modulo $53,$ since everything is.

Basically, for any $u,v$ $$u^3+v^3\equiv\left((u^3+v^3)^{35}\right)^3\pmod{53}.$$

@ThomasAndrews Why did you not insert comments into answer? They are very interesting..

By Fermat's little theorem, $(a^{35})^3=a^{105}\equiv a\pmod{53},$ for any $a,$ so it isn't really too big of a surprise.

@ThomasAndrews From your formulas very interesting is $2^3+3^3=35 \equiv {(2^3)^3} $ (mod $53$)

Not sure how you got that formula. $$2^3+3^3\equiv 35\equiv (35^{35})^3\pmod{53}.$$

@ThomasAndrews I have used the equation above and your third comment here ...

All you had t9 say was "Because $35^{35}\equiv 8.$" It looked like you horribly misread what I wrote. Rewriting $8=2^3$ in particular wasn't helpful in making your query clear. When communicating, understand that your reader cannot read your mind.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
